# С++ неправильно считает

Tags: c++

Почему неправильно считает (С++)?

```
int main(){
    long long int km;
    long long int a=8;
    cout<<"input km" << endl;
    cin>>km;
    cout<<(a*km);

    return 0;}
```

```
    Результат в консоли: 
    input km
    1e+10
    8
```

Comment: С++ считает так, как ему говорят...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что здесь

```
cin >> km;
```

вы читаете **целое число**, так что из `1e8` будет прочитано только `1`, а `e8` останется в буфере ввода.

Попробуйте ввести 100000000 :)

Comment: Проблема не совсем в этом. Например:
int vazr=8;
    long int km;
    cout <<"input km" << endl;
    cin>>km;
     cout << vazr*km << " litres";
Вводим значение km 10000000000
Получаем: 1.71799e+10 litres

Comment: Шутить изволите? https://ideone.com/cfsuwM Кстати, во многих компиляторах `long int` — это тоже 4 байта, и 10000000000 в него невпихуемо :) Может, у вас VC++ — тогда нужен `long long int`. Но вот в вывод `1.71799e+10` для целочисленных типов — простите, не верю!